# Using <experimental/filesystem> with CMake

Tags: cmake, filesystems, c++14, c++-experimental

I was using CMake to build a project that requires <experimental/filesystem> in C++14. And I got undefined symbol: _ZNSt12experimental10filesystem2v17__cxx114path14_M_split_cmptsEv when running the binary.

Did I miss anything in the cmakelist.txt?

Answer (score 2):

In this answer I'm assuming you have an older version of GCC, which doesn't support C++17 or `std::filesystem`.

For older versions of GCC, the filesystem library isn't part of the main standard library.

Instead it comes as a separate library that you need to explicitly link with.

If you don't already have a [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command you need to add one for your target, that links with the `stdc++fs` library.